# Griddle Filter Component Customization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

I am using Griddle Component and trying to customize Filter component to fit the requirement. I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onChange is not a function` error. I am following this example. https://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/docs/customization/
Here's components.

List component:

```
class UserList extends React.Component {
render(){
const users = this.props.users;
return( 
<Griddle data={users} plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]} styleConfig={styleConfig} components={{Filter}} pageProperties={{pageSize: 5}}>
  <RowDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition id="username" title="Username" className="" />
    <ColumnDefinition id="firstname" title="First Name" className="" />
    <ColumnDefinition id="lastname" title="Last Name" />
    <ColumnDefinition id="id" title="Action" customComponent={EditDeleteUser} />
  </RowDefinition>
</Griddle>
)
}
}export default UserList;
```

Custom Fiter Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router';
class Filter extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}  
onChange(e) {
 this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
}
render() {
 return (
            <div className="searchInput">
                <input 
                  type="text" 
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="search" 
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="search" className="icon icon-1202" rel="tooltip" title="search"></label>
              </div> 
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through what "this" was ... so I figured out that

```
    this.props.setFilter(e.target.value)
```

worked for me.